# Getting Exiftool duration without fuzzy time

Tags: exiftool

When I use exiftool to get the duration of an audio file, if the file is over 24 hours I get “1 day 1:23:45” instead of 25:23:45. Sometimes I get “approx 13:17:23”.

Is it possible to tell exiftool to only return HH:MM:SS regardless of how long the file actually is and if it thinks the time is approximate or not (I can strip out the approximate if I have to, but if there’s a way to specify the output format I can’t find it)?

```
exiftool -d "%H:%M:%S" -Duration Audiobook.m4a
Duration                        : 1 days 1:17:20
```

This works, assuming there its no way to get exiftool to output the hours:

```
    if [[ $DURA == *"days"* ]]; then
        EXIF=$(exiftool -duration# "$FILE")
        SEC=$(awk -F": " '/Dura/ {print $2}' <<<"$EXIF" |awk -F'.' '{print $1}')
        HOR=$(($SEC / 3600))
        MIN=$(($SEC % 3600/60))
        SES=$(($SEC % 60))
        DURA="$HOR:$MIN:$SES"
     fi
```

Comment: You could use `-duration#` instead to get the duration in pure seconds...

Comment: duration# shows seconds and fractional seconds, not what I want, but better than what I have.

Comment: The [`-d` (`-dateFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#d-FMT--dateFormat) only affects date/time tags.  Tags which are timestamps for a specific moment.  To change the duration output in exiftool, you would have to make some Perl code to do what you want and make a user-defined tag.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: no way to do this in efixtool, so work around somehow (I chose bash script, but whatever).

Comment: If this is the answer, please make sure that future readers can easily find and see all that they need to solve your problem here. Thank you.

Comment: I included my shell workaround in the original post. I didn’t think it was worth reposting that.